# TCPDF image color is not working properly (giving black and white color)

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I am using the TCPDF Library to generate a dynamic PDF. I have put a logo image in the document, but the image is showing up as black and white, instead of the original colors. The image is in the .png format, and I have included it in my html file using the `<img>` tag.
I have also tried the `pdf->image()` function, but it is giving me the same result.

[image: This is the image]

Comment: We can't read your mind, give use some sources

Comment: The image you linked to appears greyscale when I viewed it. Should it include other colors?

Comment: @AdamMoller I presume the image is supposed to look like the one here: http://www.eshopdesigners.com/